# RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid device ordinal when implementing Distributed Data Parallel in Pytorch tutorial

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, distributed

I am trying to duplicate the tutorial Distributed Data Parallel in Pytorch https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL_lsbAsL_o2CSuhUhJIiW0IkdT5C2wGWj and am getting the error RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid device ordinal. The other stackoverflow answers seem to be related to other problems or advises setting a specific GPU. Per the tutorial, torchrun is supposed to handle this when using multiple nodes/multiple GPUs. My commandline input for the first machine is (the last three items are the python file from the tutorial, #epochs, #save_interval_epochs):

```
torchrun --nproc_per_node=2 -nnodes=2 --node_rank=0 --rzdv_id=17 --rdzv_backend=c10d --rdzv_endpoint=129:82:45:141:31004 conv_distrib.py 5 5
```

The command line on the 2nd machine is the same except node_rank=1. The logs show the error is on line 72, which is part of the class Trainer code (from the tutorial) here, with a print I added.

```
60class Trainer:
61    def __init__(
62        self,
63        model: torch.nn.Module,
64        train_data: DataLoader,
65        optimizer: torch.optim.Optimizer,
66        save_every: int,
67        snapshot_path: str,
68    ) -> None:
69        self.local_rank = int(os.environ["LOCAL_RANK"])
70        self.global_rank = int(os.environ["RANK"])
71        print("local_rank global_rank", self.local_rank, self.global_rank)
72        self.model = model.to(self.local_rank)
```

In looking at the logs, the local rank seems right (0 or 1 for the two specified nproc), as does the global rank (0,1 for the 1st machine, 2,3 for the 2nd machine). However, I don't know enough to see why the device ordinal is invalid or where to look. Any advice would be really appreciated.

Log 1st machine (rank 0):

```
tarpon:~/convolution$ torchrun --nproc_per_node=2 --nnodes=2 --node_rank=0 --rdzv_id=17 --rdzv_backend=c10d --rdzv_endpoint=129.82.45.141:31004 conv_distrib.py 5 5
WARNING:torch.distributed.run:
*****************************************
Setting OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable for each process to be 1 in default, to avoid your system being overloaded, please further tune the variable for optimal performance in your application as needed.
*****************************************
local_rank global_rank 0 2
local_rank global_rank 1 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/s/chopin/b/grad/jmuth/convolution/conv_distrib.py", line 230, in <module>
    main(args.save_every, args.total_epochs, args.batch_size)
  File "/s/chopin/b/grad/jmuth/convolution/conv_distrib.py", line 217, in main
    trainer = Trainer(model, train_data, optimizer, save_every, snapshot_path)
  File "/s/chopin/b/grad/jmuth/convolution/conv_distrib.py", line 72, in __init__
    self.model = model.to(self.local_rank)
  File "/usr/local/python-env/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 927, in to
    return self._apply(convert)
  File "/usr/local/python-env/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 579, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/usr/local/python-env/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 602, in _apply
    param_applied = fn(param)
  File "/usr/local/python-env/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 925, in convert
    return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() or t.is_complex() else None, non_blocking)
**RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid device ordinal**
WARNING:torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api:Sending process 2976905 closing signal SIGTERM
ERROR:torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api:failed (exitcode: 1) local_rank: 1 (pid: 2976906) of binary: /usr/local/python-env/py39/bin/python3.9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/python-env/py39/bin/torchrun", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/python-env/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/multiprocessing/errors/__init__.py", line 345, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/python-env/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 761, in main
    run(args)
  File "/usr/local/python-env/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 752, in run
    elastic_launch(
  File "/usr/local/python-env/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 131, in __call__
    return launch_agent(self._config, self._entrypoint, list(args))
  File "/usr/local/python-env/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 245, in launch_agent
    raise ChildFailedError(
torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.errors.ChildFailedError:
============================================================
conv_distrib.py FAILED
------------------------------------------------------------
Failures:
  <NO_OTHER_FAILURES>
------------------------------------------------------------
Root Cause (first observed failure):
[0]:
  time      : 2023-04-20_17:56:54
  host      : tarpon.cs.colostate.edu
  rank      : 3 (local_rank: 1)
  exitcode  : 1 (pid: 2976906)
  error_file: <N/A>
  traceback : To enable traceback see: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/elastic/errors.html
============================================================
tarpon:~/convolution$
```

Log from 2nd machine (rank = 1):

```
neptune:~/convolution$ torchrun --nproc_per_node=2 --nnodes=2 --node_rank=1 --rdzv_id=17 --rdzv_backend=c10d --rdzv_endpoint=129.82.45.141:31004 conv_distrib.py 5 5
WARNING:torch.distributed.run:
*****************************************
Setting OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable for each process to be 1 in default, to avoid your system being overloaded, please further tune the variable for optimal performance in your application as needed.
*****************************************
local_rank global_rank 0 0
local_rank global_rank 1 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/s/chopin/b/grad/jmuth/convolution/conv_distrib.py", line 230, in <module>
    main(args.save_every, args.total_epochs, args.batch_size)
  File "/s/chopin/b/grad/jmuth/convolution/conv_distrib.py", line 217, in main
    trainer = Trainer(model, train_data, optimizer, save_every, snapshot_path)
  File "/s/chopin/b/grad/jmuth/convolution/conv_distrib.py", line 72, in __init__
    self.model = model.to(self.local_rank)
  File "/usr/local/python-env/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 927, in to
    return self._apply(convert)
  File "/usr/local/python-env/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 579, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/usr/local/python-env/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 602, in _apply
    param_applied = fn(param)
  File "/usr/local/python-env/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 925, in convert
    return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() or t.is_complex() else None, non_blocking)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid device ordinal
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
WARNING:torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api:Sending process 3152965 closing signal SIGTERM
ERROR:torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api:failed (exitcode: 1) local_rank: 1 (pid: 3152966) of binary: /usr/local/python-env/py39/bin/python3.9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/python-env/py39/bin/torchrun", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/python-env/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/multiprocessing/errors/__init__.py", line 345, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/python-env/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 761, in main
    run(args)
  File "/usr/local/python-env/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 752, in run
    elastic_launch(
  File "/usr/local/python-env/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 131, in __call__
    return launch_agent(self._config, self._entrypoint, list(args))
  File "/usr/local/python-env/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 245, in launch_agent
    raise ChildFailedError(
torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.errors.ChildFailedError:
============================================================
conv_distrib.py FAILED
------------------------------------------------------------
Failures:
  <NO_OTHER_FAILURES>
------------------------------------------------------------
Root Cause (first observed failure):
[0]:
  time      : 2023-04-20_17:56:54
  host      : neptune.cs.colostate.edu
  rank      : 1 (local_rank: 1)
  exitcode  : 1 (pid: 3152966)
  error_file: <N/A>
  traceback : To enable traceback see: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/elastic/errors.html
============================================================
neptune:~/convolution$ ^C
neptune:~/convolution$
```